# How to access an array element whose key starts with some unique string in PHP?

Tags: arrays, key, prefix

From the following array:

```
area = Array
    (
        sur12 => 2
        abb12 => 5
        sur13 => 6
        abb13 => 4
        sur14 => 8
        abb14 => 4
        sur15 => 2
        abb15 => 5
        abb16 => 8
        abb17 => 5
        abb18 => 4
        abb19 => 2
        abb20 => 6
        abb21 => 9
        abb22 => 5
        abb23 => 9
        abb24 => 8
        sur_count15 => 4
        abb_count24 => 2
    )
```

how do I access `area['sur_count15']` if I only know the prefix `sur_count`, or `area['abb_count24']` if I only know the prefix `abb_count`?

Is there any way to do this in PHP, like, e.g. in CSS where I can access an ID that starts with `abc_count` by using `[id*="abc_count"]`?

The prefix is unique to the first 3 characters.

Comment: Have you considered using `array_keys($area)`? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471120/php-function-array-key-exists-and-regular-expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the answer to my other question over at [How to get a subset of $_POST array with keys starting with a prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583591/how-to-get-a-subset-of-post-array-with-keys-starting-with-a-prefix). If only I could restructure the array, but that's a no-go for now. Thanks, y'all.

Answer (score 0):

one of the solution to your above problem could be as 
below but i strongly advise you to look for another 
solution because this one may not be very optimizable solution :

```
for(int $i=0;$i<30;$i++)
{
  if(in_array('sur_count' . $i,$area))
  {
    //your code here
  }
  if(in_array('abb_count' . $i,$area))
  {
    //your code here
  }
}
```

may be this could help you a bit.....

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the array_keys, then searching this for a match using regexp `/sur_count[0-9]*/` or similar.

See here for more details: 
[php function array_key_exists and regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471120/php-function-array-key-exists-and-regular-expressions)