# Get only the array elements with certain keys

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pattern Match on a Array Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595763/pattern-match-on-a-array-key)

I need to get all the elements in an array with a specific key pattern. For example in this array:

```
$items = array(
   "a"         => "1",
   "b"         => "2",
   "special_1" => "3",
   "c"         => "4",
   "special_2" => "5",
   "special_3" => "6",
   "d"         => "7"
);
```

I would need all elements with a key containing the string `special_`. These should define a new array:

```
$special_items = array(
   "special_1" => "3",
   "special_2" => "5",
   "special_3" => "6",
);
```

Is there a smart method besides a `while` loop?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583591/how-to-get-a-subset-of-post-array-with-keys-starting-with-a-prefix , my answer which provides a custom function named `preg_grep_keys()` may be useful to people interested in this question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How about this?

```
$special_items = array();

foreach($items as $key => $val) {
    if(substr($key, 0, 8) == 'special_')
        $special_items[$key] = $val;
}
```

Comment: Yep, the easiest to manage too.

Answer (score 7):

First you need to get an array containing the keys. [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array-keys)

Then, you need to filter the keys to find the ones you want. [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array-filter)

Use this callback:

```
function($a) {return substr($a,0,8) == "special_";}
```

Then flip the array so that the keys are keys again instead of values. [`array_flip`](http://php.net/array_flip)

Finally, intersect those keys with the original array. [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/array-intersect-key)

Result:

```
$special_items = array_intersect_key($items,array_flip(array_filter(array_keys($items),function($a) {return substr($a,0,8) == "special_";})));
```

Comment: Yes, but a little bit more tricky than a simple for/if

Comment: That’s exactly the generic solution I was looking for. I need to make it a utility function. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `FilterIterator`

```
$iterator = new SpecialFilter($items, 'special');
var_dump(iterator_to_array($iterator));
```

Output

```
array
  'special_1' => string '3' (length=1)
  'special_2' => string '5' (length=1)
  'special_3' => string '6' (length=1)
```

Class Used

```
class SpecialFilter extends FilterIterator {
    private $f;
    public function __construct(array $items, $filter) {
        $object = new ArrayObject( $items );
        $this->f = $filter;
        parent::__construct( $object->getIterator() );
    }
    public function accept() {
        return 0 === strpos( $this->getInnerIterator()->key(), $this->f );
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! OO tech is the winner. Why make the thing simple when we can complicate them? 2 new, one inheritance (at least) to do 3 lines of code: for/if/doit

Comment: `Is there a smart method besides a while loop?` Yes If `for/if/doit` is sufficient they would be nothing like `Iterators`

Comment: Nice, clean, test-able... +1

Comment: @Aubin Right, because who would want an easy to use and extend utility class when they can just copy paste blocks of code everywhere? I genuinely feel for anyone inheriting your code.

Genuinely this is the best answer to OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$special_items = array_intersect_key(array_flip(preg_grep('/^special_\d+/', array_keys($items))), $items);
```

Please don't actually use that. Just use a foreach loop with strpos + an if statement like all normal people would.

Comment: Well, exactly what I currently have. +1

Comment: Incorrect use of `array_intersect_key`. -1

Comment: Arguments in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
$keys = preg_grep( "/special_/i", array_keys( $items ) );

$new_array = array();

foreach( $keys as $k )
{
    $new_array[ $k ] = $items[ $k ];
}
```